# Сменить пользователя GitHub в Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

В настройках идеи отображается авторизированным только один пользователь, на аккаунт которого и происходит импорт проекта. Но коммиты на GitHub-е отображаются от лица другого пользователя, из аккаунта которого я давно вышел в идеи. Перепроверил разные способы, но ничего не помогло, как будто этот аккаунт привязан к моему профилю JetBrains

Comment: `Но коммиты на GitHub-е отображаются от лица другого пользователя` тот факт, что вы вышли из аккаунта, не означает, что история репозитория изменится.

Comment: Вполне возможно что у вас просто установлены параметры через git config --global user.email и git config --global user.name

Comment: Да, действительно, все оказалось именно так